# Issue retrieving a ExecutionContext from a SkipListener

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to retrieve a spring batch `ExecutionContext` from a `SkipListener`.

Here is what I have attempted (I rely on annotations instead of interfaces in order to implement my listeners):

```java
import com.xxxx.domain.UserAccount;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.BeforeStep;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.OnSkipInWrite;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSendException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class MailSkipListener {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @BeforeStep
    public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @OnSkipInWrite
    public void logSkippedEmail(UserAccount userAccount, Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof MailSendException) {
            MailSendException e = (MailSendException) t;
            log.warn("FailedMessages: " + e.getFailedMessages());
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `logSkippedEmail` method is never executed when a `MailSendException` is raised. When I remove the `saveStepExecution` method, the `logSkippedEmail` is again executed in case of a `MailSendException`.

I register my `MailSkipListener` as follows:

```java
@Bean
public Step messagesDigestMailingStep(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("messagesDigestMailingStep")
            .<UserAccount, UserAccount>chunk(5)

            ...

            .writer(itemWriter)
            .listener(mailSkipListener)//Here
            .build();
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is retrieving an `ExecutionContext` from my `SkipListener`. How can this be achieved? It seems there's no way to autowire the`ExecutionContext`.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old question, but I just struggled with this too.
I ended up registering the skiplistener twice in order for it to work, once as a StepExecutionListener and another as a SkipListener.
It sucks, but it seems to work:

```java
@Bean
public Step messagesDigestMailingStep(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("messagesDigestMailingStep")
        .<UserAccount, UserAccount>chunk(5)

        ...

        .writer(itemWriter)
        .listener((StepExecutionListener) mailSkipListener) // <--- 1
        .listener((SkipListener) mailSkipListener)          // <--- 2
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old Question, but I had to deal with this myself, and have put together the following implementation, wherein I made the SkipListener also implement the StepExecutionListener, and adding the same class as both the SkipListener and StepExecutionListener.

```
@Component
public class PersonImportListener implements SkipListener<Person, Person>, StepExecutionListener {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    private StepExecution stepExecution;
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable throwable) {
        logger.warn("Line skipped on read", throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Person person, Throwable throwable) {
        logger.warn("Bean skipped on write", throwable);
        logger.warn("Execution Context" + stepExecution);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(Person person, Throwable throwable) {
        logger.warn("Bean skipped on process", throwable);
    }
}
```

And use this class as a listener for StepExecutionListener and also SkipListener.

```
@Bean
public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
    PersonImportListener listener = new PersonImportListener();
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipLimit(10)
            .skip(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
            .listener((StepExecutionListener) listener)
            .listener((SkipListener) listener)
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [`StepExecutionListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html) on your `MailSkipListener` to save the context in your `stepExecution` during the `beforeStep()` method :

```java
public class MailSkipListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
         this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thrax. This is what I have tried above but using annotations instead of an interface