# Spring Batch validating line and sending email if validation fail

Tags: spring-batch

I want to do some validation on line I process and if validation fail, I would like to send email that we can't process that line.
How can I achieved that? I'm using FlatFileItemReader and processor after it.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using FlatFileItemReader and processor after it

That's how I would do it too. In your processor, you can implement the validation logic and throw an exception for invalid items. This is one of the typical use cases for an item processor BTW. The [Validating input](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#validatingInput) section of the reference documentation shows an example.

You can then configure the exception to be skippable and use a `SkipListener` to store invalid items (either in memory or to a file or a db table, etc). Finally, you would use an additional tasklet step to send an email with those invalid items.

HTH.

Comment: do you know how can I send content currently processing line into processor? As I will validate it there I want also to send email with content of that line.

Comment: You can create a custom exception class and set the skipped line in it so that the skip listener can get the invalid line. You can get inspiration from `FlatFileParseException` which is thrown when reading an invalid line. You would do the same but for processing.

Comment: ok, understood, but I'm mapping line to object in reader and i don't have line in processor, is there a way to somehow make it available there?

Comment: ah ok I see, I thought you were looking for how to pass the info from processor to the skip listener. To pass the raw line from the reader to the processor, I would add a String field in the mapped item called for example `mappedFrom` which would contain the raw string line from which is was mapped. This needs to be done in your reader and will allow you to know the original line for invalid items in the processor.

Comment: I've made everything (listener, exception) but when I added faultTolerant, skip and skipLimit I am not able to use build() method in step configuration

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine any recommendations on how to store values in memory? I'm using batch as part of a rest service and it looks as if the SkipListener is instantiated on startup.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine one thought I had was to add an extra field to the dto to hold the validation errors and validate with the processor. If any errors just add to the dto field and skip during the writer step. Not sure what the best approach is though.

Comment: @CodeJunkie In regards to storing skipped items in memory a map should be fine. Usually the number of skipped items is not very high (unless there is something fundamentally wrong with the data) so storing them in memory should be ok. The typical use case I see regularly is to save them in a db table and process them later on after examination. The idea of adding an extra field to the dto is also nice, I see no issues with this alternative.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine any recommendations on where to put the map and still have access to it later on in the process?

Comment: It could be a shared map bean (a concurrent one if in multi-threadded env) in your application context. Another way to address this is to put skipped items in the job execution context and retrieve them later on when appropriate (in a subsequent step or after the entire job). Care should be taken to avoid storing a lot of data in the execution context.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I decided to use a temp db as you pointed out above. If I'm catching the validation exception with the skip listener and then writing to the temp table, how to do I get the Job Id in the skip listener to append to the temp table record? Should I create a custom validation implementation and insert in the item processor or should I somehow get the job id in the item processor and append it to the dto? I'm not seeing any way to get the Job Id from the skip listener, so if you have another suggestion, I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Good move, that's the best option IMO as it allows you to analyse skipped items from a persistent store after the job is finished. Now if you want to get the job ID in your listener, all you have to do is to try to get access to the step execution (from which you can get the parent job execution and then job instance). There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987089/issue-retrieving-a-executioncontext-from-a-skiplistener

Answer (score 0):

I have problem after adding faultTolerant, skipLimit an skip into the step config. In this setup I'm unable to use build()

```
return stepBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .<RegisterUserRequest, RegisterUserRequest>chunk(2000)
                .reader(registerUserFromFileReader)
                .processor(registerUserProcessor)
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipLimit(50000)
                .skip(RegisterUserLineException.class)
                .listener(registerUserSkipListener)
                .writer(userRegistration)
                .listener(registerUserFinalizer)
                .build() //doesn't work
```

Comment: The order of methods matters because some of them return a `SimpleStepBuilder` and some others return `FaultTolerantStepBuilder`. You can defer the `.faultTolerant()` + skip/skipLimit to the end and it should work.