# How to get the `JobId` in the `SkipListener`?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How to get the `JobId` in the `SkipListener`? I used below logic but its not working.

```
private Long jobId;

@BeforeStep
public void getJobId(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.jobId = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobId();
}
```

I also tried below

```
@Value("#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}")
private Long jobId;
```

But getting the below

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'stepExecution' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1569) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'stepExecution' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:55) ~[spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:272) ~[spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue retrieving a ExecutionContext from a SkipListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987089/issue-retrieving-a-executioncontext-from-a-skiplistener)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine -  Unless I dont do the `@StepScope` on the SkipListener bean I dont get value in the JobId, I am using Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE and `@EnableBatchProcessing` was thinking because of this things will be bydefault under the `@StepScope`

Comment: The first approach (implementing the SkipListener interface) should work with adding step scope. The second approach (injecting the stepExecution using a SpEL expression) requires the listener to be declared as a step scoped bean.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, yes I have implemented the SkipListener interface and added @StepScope over the bean, agree both ways it works. Is this fine if we define reader bean with the StepScope and not the processor and writer beans? Please confirm.

Comment: ok, in that case I added an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach (implementing the `SkipListener` interface) should work with adding step scope. The second approach (injecting the stepExecution using a SpEL expression) requires the listener to be declared as a step scoped bean.

> Is this fine if we define reader bean with the StepScope and not the processor and writer beans? Please confirm

Yes that's ok. Not all step components need to be step-scoped together.